# Express res.cookie not setting cookie on client side

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, samesite

I am trying to configure my JWT through http-only cookies

```
const signIn = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    const access_token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, jwtSecret, {
      expiresIn: token_expiry_time,
    });
    const refresh_token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, jwtRefreshSecret, {
      expiresIn: refresh_token_expiry_time,
    });
    res.cookie('access_token', access_token, { httpOnly: true });
    res.cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, { httpOnly: true });
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: true,
      data: {
        user: {
          id: user._id,
        },
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    Server.serverError(res, err);
  }
};
```

but at the client-side it refuses to set the cookie in the browser, it returns the error "cannot set cookie because same-site is not 'None' ", After setting `sameSite:'None'` on the server side, it then gave the error "same-site set to 'None' needs to have a 'Secure' field", I then set `secure:true` on the backend but it doesn't work because I am not using https for development.

client-side code

```
const onSubmit = (cred) => {
    setLoading(true);
    restAPI
      .post('auth/signin', cred)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(false);
        console.log(data.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setError({
          status: true,
          message: err.response.data.message,
        });
      });
  };
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Please share the code of client side, specially the api call to signIn method

Comment: Hmm, with which library is done your restApi ?